# how to setup external fingerprint device in Ubuntu

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I need help to setup external fingerprint device in Ubuntu 
fingerprint device brand morpho model msf1300e or mantra mfs 100

Answer (score 0):

As far as mantra is concerned, the company provides driver for their product. Just download that and install it. please read the instructions carefully before installation.